# Conditional heat mapping

Tags: excel, charts, filter

I am looking to make a heat map (bubble graph) which allows you to filter what plots on the graph based on a few descriptive criteria.

In the bubble graph, there are three "scoring" variables (x-axis, y-axis and bubble size), but each item in my graph also has two associated descriptive data points. The first data point can be three possible options (x,y,z), and the second data point is a yes, no question. I am looking to be able to filter what shows in the heat map based on the two descriptive criteria.

For example: Only show things in the bubble chart where descriptive criteria #1 = X and descriptive criteria #2 = Yes

I have attached a sample worksheet which might be more helpful to understand what I am looking for.

Thanks

Comment: Did you forget to add the sample worksheet?

Answer (score 0):

I'd you can do this with most of the charting libraries, but you'll have to write a data filter yourself. Take a look at this example: http://www.amcharts.com/inspiration/motion-chart/

It is based on a famous Gapminder widget. If you click on a continent on the top-right, the bubbles of other continents will become barely visible. This is done by simply looping through the data and setting opacity of all bubbles except the selected continents to some close to 0 value.

Disclaimer: I am the author of amCharts.